Kali linux cursor control keys is still in movement even if keyboard left/right arrows button are released
When I hold down the left or right arrow keys to move my cursor, the cursor moves correctly but if I release the button suddenly, the cursor keeps moving for a little while, as if there is a delay which is kind of frustrating as I can't find the right position.
I am using zsh and the latest version of Kali (Kali 2024). Also, I am using Gnome. Maybe it's a Gnome issue? (The VM is not cloud-based so no delays from internet connection; I've also changed the options setting repeat (keys-->speed repeat, keys-->delay) but those are for typing issues not for cursor movement)
I have delved into this and I am very close to figuring it out but I need help. I've set these values for Gnome for numpad keys 2,4,6,8 (which act like arrows when NumLock is disabled). These buttons seem to work properly when holding/releasing. The cursor movement speed is OK and when I release the keys, they immediately stop just like any other distribution. The problem now is how to pass the same values for the classical cursor control keys because those don't work properly.
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-max-speed 2000;
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-init-delay 20;
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-accel-time 2000;
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable true;

└─$ xset q                  
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000002
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  600    repeat rate:  31
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,built-ins
DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On


gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard

org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay uint32 500
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat-interval uint32 30


You mentioned a VM, where does that come into it? Are you running Kali on a local VM? Also, is this issue occurring only when using zsh, or does it affect GUI tools? Other shells?

"cursor movement" (the arrow keys) ARE typed keys, which, in VT100 mode, send multicharacter strings.

@ terdon yes that's true i am running Kali Linux locally on a VMware workstation machine. The problem occurs on the terminal only and not other apps have this issue

Have you installed guest tools?

@vidarlo yes of course, that's obvious i think
